# How to calculate a DAX expression at specific levels

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to perform a specific calculation at various grouped up attributes and then average those values at higher levels.  Here is an example of what the data might look like:

[image]

The Formula field is

```
1 - ABS(Forecast - Actual)/Actual
```

You can see in the picture that if I were to do this calculation at the lowest level and then in Power BI I want to drop just the Average of the Formula field you can see that this would come out at 2%.  This is not the number that I want to get.

Now if I try and do this in a different fashion and just sum up all of the forecast and actual numbers and perform the same formula against these This is not what I want to get either.  I end up with something like this

[image]

What I am really trying to do is to perform that formula at the MaterialNumber/Plant Level and then get the average of those numbers.  So it would look something like this:

[image]

Can someone help me in how I would accomplish something like this.

Comment: Your formula should be divide by Actual, not by Forecast?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo, but the same question still applies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "Data" for your table name.

Create a measure:

```
Total Forecast = SUM(Data[Forecast])
```

Another measure:

```
Total Actual =SUM(Data[Actual])
```

Third measure:

```
Variance = ABS([Total Forecast] - [Total Actual])
```

Forth measure:

```
Variance % = 1 - DIVIDE([Variance],[Total Actual])
```

Finally:

```
Average Variance % =
AVERAGEX(
   SUMMARIZE(
       Data, 
       Data[MaterialNumber],
       Data[Plant],
      "Variance Percent", [Variance %]),
[Variance Percent]
)
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

1. Calculations are broken down into multiple measures to make code cleaner and easier to understand;
2. Last measure works as follows: we summarize data by material and plant and calculate variance % for each group. Then AverageX iterates over these groups and averages their variances.